# Parse only second part using Python and re

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have data:

```
audio_9813314_456239162
audio_9813314_456239175
audio_9813314_456239145
audio_9813314_456239178
```

I need only second part of digits, like

```
456239162
456239175
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, I loop thru data and split data where `_` and took last part `[-1]`

```
data = ["audio_9813314_456239162",
"audio_9813314_456239175",
"audio_9813314_456239145",
"audio_9813314_456239178"]

new_data = []
for i in data:
  last_part = i.split("_")[-1]
  new_data.append(last_part)

print(new_data)
```

output:

```
['456239162', '456239175', '456239145', '456239178']
output:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here so you can pick and choose whichever. Here are two ways you can get this.

1. A simple `findall`

If you know the numbers that you need will always be at the end or at the second position, you can use `findall`

```
import re
str1 = 'audio_9813314_456239162'

print re.findall('(\d+)', str1)[-1]
print re.findall('(\d+)', str1)[1]
```

Output

```
456239162
456239162
```

2. Search for the term, explicitly, using `match`

Match starts from the first character, from left to right, so you'll need to account for everything before the digits that you're looking for. Note: The 0th index is the whole string so we get the 1st index, instead.

```
print re.match('.+_\d+_(\d+)', str1).group(1)
```